# FCM Notification not working in oppo(color OS) after allowing Auto Startup

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM in my android application. Notification working fine when the app is in the background but after killing from the background notification is not working.

My mobile is **oppo f9 pro**

I have manually enabled auto startup and enabled allow in the background.

[image]

**Enabled in background**

[image]

**My Firebase Service**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "myFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d(TAG, "From : " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Data : " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    }

}
}
```

**Sending Payload**

```
{
"notification":{"title":"testing of notification - new ","body":"body of notification ","sound":"Enabled"

},
"data":{
    "id":74,
    "callFrom":"test",
    "other_info":"other detail in other info"
},
"to":"c5V-l4poMYI:APA91bFk8DO6upFN9dSXjI3d9UXpRUvmdzPo9OyUV9LnLJhCA6vBQ4y6TuXWHg1vaGM0SV6bEOLDW38UFEsVhcHFRvT7oIkGNmtd2v6516ABh6MyvkuoFP7gwUJWOPQRCaPsVg8_O2ot"
}
```

Comment: whats the logcat message when you sending message?